# Get result of certbot run within docker within ansible

Tags: linux, docker, ansible, docker-compose, certbot

I'm running [certbot](https://hub.docker.com/r/certbot/certbot/) within a docker container. I'm using ansible to start it via [`docker_compose`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/docker_compose_module.html).

When the container is started, certbot takes a little while to do its thing, and then the container exits (with results printed to stdout and to a log).

But when automated via ansible, it starts the container and then moves to the next task. So I don't know whether the process succeeded, I only know that the container was started.

How can I make ansible wait for it to exit, so I can get the result by querying stdout or the log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`wait_for`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/wait_for_module.html) module.

```
- name: run certbot container
  docker_compose:
    project_src: path-to-docker-compose
    state: present
  register: result

- name: wait for certbot container to exit
  when: result is success
  wait_for:
    path: logfile-or-something-created-by-certbot-on-success-or-failure
    state: present
    timeout: 20
```

Alternative: run manually within `shell` module, but it's harder to manage failure.